# How to loop through different schemas and execute some sql on each?

Tags: oracle, session, schema, alter

I have a case where I have 70 oracle schemas and I have to execute the same script on each

which would be the best way to achieve this.

Is it possible with a CURSOR?

For now I'm doing it with

```
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = SCHEMA_1;
====
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = SCHEMA_2;
====
ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = SCHEMA_3;
====
```

And I replace the "====" with my script, I+m doing it with Notepad++ but I have to prepare the script manually and if the script is long I have to split it in multiple chunks without new lines and do a replace for each chunk

I would like to automate this a little bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I offer the following semi-automatic way, which does not automate your task, but cuts down on the search and replace.

If you are using SQL*Plus, you can execute a file with the following syntax:

```
@myscriptfile.sql
```

If you would want to do that once for each schema, you could generate the code by querying the dictionary:

```
select 'ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = ' || owner || ';
       @myscriptfile.sql'
  from dba_users
 where <your filter>;
```

Then you would just copy/paste the result of that query in sqlplus. It is probably possible to spool that to file and execute it.

Comment: sounds interesting ... I'll try it

Comment: @simon, did you end up using the above approach? Will you consider accepting the answer if you found it helpful to your problem?

Comment: jep ... sory for the dealy..the answer was helpful..tnx