# How to update value of fields in a table found in every schema on an Oracle Server

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I need to update the value of two fields in a table and in every schema containing that table on an Oracle Server (11g).  I am from the SQL Server world, but recognize that the architecture is different with multiple schemas under a single instance, not multiple databases under a single instance.  The reason for this update is to ensure that while database development and testing takes place on copies of client databases, the clients do not accidentally receive emails (according to settings defined in certain columns of a table in each schema/database).

I am using SQL Developer, but could also apply SQLplus instead.  Assuming the Server name is "myServer", the tablename is "myTable" and the fields are "Field1" and "Field2" of this table, can somebody help in providing some SQL that will perform a global update of all schemas on myServer setting Field1 = 'N' and Field2 = NULL in myTable?  Or direct me to a link that does answer this question?  I first ran multiple searches and found nothing.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through diferent schemas and execute some sql on each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297268/how-to-loop-through-diferent-schemas-and-execute-some-sql-on-each)

Comment: This is close, but vague lacking needed details discussed in the question.  The answer applying the CTE hit the nail on the head.  Thank you for providing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL

```
FOR tbl IN (SELECT owner, table_name
              FROM dba_tables
             WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE')
LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'update ' || tbl.owner || '.' || tbl.table_name ||
                    '  set field1 = ''N'', ' ||
                    '      field2 = null ';
END LOOP;
```

You can add some additional logging and you probably want to build the SQL statement in a local variable so that you can log it if something goes wrong.  This also assumes that you're running as a user that has access to `dba_tables`.  You could use `all_tables` if you want to update every table with that name that you have access to (which might not cover every table in the database).

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly.  Sorry for the delay in responding, I was out of the office Thursday and Friday of last week.